# What's a workable low hassle privacy latch for the inside of an interior door (against the jamb)

Tags: doors, latches

I need to add a privacy latch on this side of this interior door. (*Photo #1*)

I looked through an extensive set of latches at a local hardware store and none of them had the right strike plate or receiver for this situation Except for a sliding barrel bolt, which I don't want because they tend to slide when not wanted and will eventually bash into the door frame.

Nearby (*Photo #2*) I used a barrel bolt but there I embedded the receiver behind new trim, not an option for the door in photo #1.

What is a workable latch for this type of situation, something that stays out of the way when not needed?

[image: right angle door latch]

[image]

Comment: Please _strongly_ consider the safety concerns noted in [Ecnerwal's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/207136/34147). That said, the barrel bolt will work without its associated loop - just drill a hole directly into the trim. Yes, it will wear somewhat over time, but that may be the price you pay.

Comment: Drilling a hole in the trim will leave only about 1/8" of wood to secure against pulling.  I could put the barrel bolt on a block of wood to increase that distance.

This door leads to an egress dead end, so there is not a safety issue at play.

Comment: You noted in the comments on answers that this is a _theoretical_ question, not one for the door pictured. That would have been very good info to have included in your original question as that may have changed answers.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly a sliding **vertical** bolt, as more typically seen on the "non-knob side" of double doors?

Or hang the key to that deadbolt on the doorframe, since it's already there - change to a double-cylinder if it's not an egress path and the other side is a latch, or turn it around and don't need the key on this side. Or post a notice that it's not to be opened if closed unless there's an emergency... depends on the level of "privacy" required.

Presumably finding the key for the doorknob lock is a lost hope.

Life-safety-wise, consider that there are reasons (occupant passed out or otherwise unable to open from inside) that interior "privacy locks" (typical of bathroom/bedroom doors) have a means to be bypassed in an emergency, and that anything which blocks/locks an egress path is a ***bad idea!***

Comment: This is not an egress path, as anyone going through this door is trapped in a room that has no egress.

Finding the key to the mortise lock is an option.

But the question was meant as a generic: what kind of latch can work?

----------------

The existing deadbolt is not what you think either, on the other side it's a surface lock.  The same receiver issue applies.

Answer (score 1):

Your door already has a deadbolt. They have the same form factor as a door knob.  Just buy a “privacy” (bathroom) door knob set and replace the deadbolt with that.

Comment: That's a 1925 mortise lock, not as straightforward to replace.  Besides, I asked the question as a generic, not just for this particular door.

Comment: @Bryce I'm talking about the deadbolt *above* the mortice lock.  "as a generic",  *"I need to add a privacy latch on this side of **this** interior door"** pictures follow.